# SAS PROC IMPORT Multiple SAV Files- Force SPSS Value Labels to Create UNIQUE SAS Format Names

Tags: sas, spss

Sometimes if I import multiple SAV files into the SAS work library, one variable imported later on overwrites the display text (i.e., the format) of an earlier imported variable with a similar name.

I've determined that this is because the later dataset's variable produces a **format name** for the custom format (from SPSS Values Labels) that is identical to **format name** from the earlier variable, even though the variables have different definitions in the Value Labels attributes in the SAV files.

Is there a way to force SAS to not re-use the same format names by automatically checking at PROC IMPORT whether a format name already exists in the work library format library before auto-naming a new custom format? Or is there any other way of preventing this from happening?

Here is my code as well as an example of the variable names, format names, etc.

```
proc import out=Dataset1 datafile="S:\folder\Dataset1.SAV"
dbms=SAV replace; 
run;
proc import out=DatasetA datafile="S:\folder\DatasetA.SAV"
dbms=SAV replace; 
run;
```

Dataset1 contains variable Question_1. The original SPSS Values Labels are 1=Yes 2=No. When this dataset is imported, SAS automatically generates the Format Name QUESTION., for Question_1. When only Dataset1 is imported, the definition of format QUESTION. corresponds to the SPSS Value Labels for Question_1 in Dataset1.SAV

DatasetA contains variable Question_A with SPSS Value Labels 1=Agree 2=Unsure 3=Disagree. When this dataset is imported after Dataset1, SAS automatically generates the Format Name QUESTION. for Question_A, *even though the work library already contains a format named QUESTION.*. Therefore, this overwrites the definition of format QUESTION. that was generated when Dataset1 was imported. Once DatasetA is imported, the definition of format QUESTION. corresponds to the SPSS Value Labels for Question_A in DatasetA.SAV

Therefore, when Dataset1 and DatasetA are both imported, Variable Question_1 and Question_A both have the format name QUESTION assigned to them - And the definition of the format QUESTION. in the SAS work folder corresponds to the SPSS Value Labels in DatasetA.SAV, not Dataset1.SAV. Therefore, Question_1 will display as 1=Agree 2=Unsure, even though the variable values actually mean 1=Yes 2=No.

I would ideally like for these two variables to produce distinct custom format names at their import step, automatically. Is there any way to make this happen? Alternatively, is there any other way that prevent this type of overwriting from occurring?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to prevent literal overwriting is to point to a different format catalog for each SPSS file that is being read using the FMTLIB= optional statement.

```
proc import out=dataset1 replace 
   datafile="S:\folder\Dataset1.SAV" dbms=SAV 
; 
   fmtlib=work.fmtcat1;
run;
proc import out=dataset2 replace 
   datafile="S:\folder\Dataset2.SAV" dbms=SAV 
; 
   fmtlib=work.fmtcat2;
run;
```

You can then work later to rename the conflicting formats (and change the attached format in the dataset to use the new name).

So if the member name and format name are short enough you should be able to generate a unique new name by appending the two (add something in between to avoid conflict).  So something like this will rename the formats, change the format name attached to the variables and rebuild the formats into the WORK.FORMATS catalog.

```
%macro sav_import(file,memname);
%if 0=%length(&memname) %then %let memname=%scan(&file,-2,\./);

proc import datafile=%sysfunc(quote(&file)) dbms=save
  out=&memname replace
; 
  fmtlib=work.&memname ;
run;

proc format lib=work.&memname cntlout=formats;
run;

data formats ;
  set formats end=eof;
  by fmtname type notsorted;
  oldname=fmtname;
  fmtname=catx('_',"&memname",oldname);
run;

proc contents data=&memname noprint out=contents;
run;

proc sql noprint;
  select distinct catx(' ',c.name,cats(f.fmtname,'.'))
    into :fmtlist separated by ' '
  from contents c inner join formats f
  on c.format = f.oldname
  ;
quit;

proc datasets nolist lib=work;
  modify &memname;
    format &fmtlist ;
  run;
quit;

proc format lib=work.formats cntlin=formats;
run;

%mend sav_import;

%sav_import(S:\folder\Dataset1.SAV);
%sav_import(S:\folder\Dataset2.SAV);
```

Comment: Thanks Tom. This makes sense that it can't be done more automatically. I am working with more than 2 datasets at once, with hundreds of variables per dataset, so I'm hoping to automate as much as possible. Here is what I would do in order to fix it as you described. If you see anything that could be more efficient, I appreciate any advice: (1) Get meta data datasets of var names + format names. (2) Merge to save only non-unique format names + what variables they are assigned to in which datasets. (3) Get datasets of format names and their definitions (one value per row, using

Comment: (continued) proc format cntlout=). (4) Limit format definitions datasets to only non-unique format names. (5) Merge these non-unique format names format definition datasets with eachother by format name, variable value, and value definition. (6) Save rows where there is any definition difference (i.e., the format name matches but the value is only in one format, or the value is defined in both formats but the value definition differs. (7) Use this list to go back and save ALL rows for non-unique format names that had any such discrepancy (product of this step = list of format names, values,

Comment: (continued) and value definitions for any non-unique format name with differences in definitions across datasets, also including variable names that the formats are assigned to in different datasets). (8) Manually rename the formats in the separate fmtlibs and reassign to variables (or maybe this has to be done after its in the work lib - will figure this out easily). (9) Save the contents of all the separate fmtlibs into the work library so the datasets can be used normally. Thanks for considering my follow up question

Comment: (Also just to be clear, when I said "Manually rename" in step (8) I meant that the inspection and decision-making process needs to be manual, and the syntax to rename and reassign formats has to be written for the specific format names/variables.

Comment: If the formats created by PROC IMPORT are simple VALUE -> LABEL mappings then you can convert them into data using CNTLOUT= option of PROC FORMAT.  You can then search for name conflicts and have a rule for renaming the formats.  Or you could add a step where you report the list and let users update a data file to drive the renaming.  Note you can also analyze the value/label pairs and eliminate the duplicates to make the problem smaller.  That can also be programmed.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was thinking of doing in broad strokes. When you say that I could have a "rule of renaming the formats" when I create the CNTLOUT dataset, are you talking about programming this process and somehow automating it, or just identifying naming conventions for myself, and then manually writing code to change each name and reassign formats to dataset variables. That I know of, there would not be a simple way for me to automate this step without creating a somewhat complex macro, which would not save time for me.

Comment: If you fmtnames and member names are short just use cats(memname,fmtname) as the new name for the format.  Both memname and fmtname is 32 bytes so if both are only 8 characters then no issue.  Make sure the new name does not end in a number.  You could also just generate the newnames using a counter.  Something like FnnnnF.

Comment: Great, thank you so much, using CATS is a good idea.

Comment: Add an underscore to prevent name collision. For example AB+C vs A+BC.  So use `catx('_',memname,fmtname)`