# Reading SAV labels instead of values on SAS Proc Import

Tags: import, sas, label

I'm importing a SAV file to SAS using proc import and wondering if it's possible import the data labels instead of the values. For example my SAV file has a variable which contains a 1 and 0. They are labelled as 1 = Yes and 0 = No. Is there a way to import the 'Yes' and 'No' instead of the 1 & 0?

Thank you much!

Comment: Did you provide a catalog name for PROC IMPORT to use for writing the formats for converting the stored values into desired display values (aka data labels)?  Did you include that format catalog in your FMTSEARCH list of format catalogs to search when looking for formats?

Comment: Read this question/answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62999858/sas-proc-import-multiple-sav-files-force-spss-value-labels-to-create-unique-sas